# Net_Tokyo_Tyrantで頻繁に書き込むと'111, Connection refused'というエラーが出ててしまいます。

Tags: php

現在、Net_TokyoTyrantを利用してphpからデータベースを操作しているのですが、頻繁に書き込みを行うと下記のエラーが出て、データベースが落ちてしまいます。

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Net_TokyoTyrantNetworkException' with message '111, Connection refused' in /usr/share/pear/Net/TokyoTyrant.php:53 Stack trace: #0
```

また、TokyoTyrant.phpの53行目付近は下記の通りです。

```
４８：    public function connect($server, $port, $timeout = 10)
４９：    {
５０：        $this->close();
５１：        $this->socket = @fsockopen($server,$port, $this->errorNo, $errorMessage, $timeout);
５２：        if (! $this->socket) {
５３：            throw new Net_TokyoTyrantNetworkException(sprintf('%s, %s', $this->errorNo, $errorMessage));
５４：        }
５５：        $this->connect = true;
５６：    }
```

何か解決方法はないでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　http://qiita.com/yassan0113/items/a3d813d097541b226052

Comment: マルチポスト　http://okwave.jp/qa/q9236754.html

Comment: 「頻繁に書き込みを行うと」とはどの程度なのか、書き込みを行っている実際のコード、システム構成（コメントを見るとマルチクライアント?)などの詳細が必要です

Answer (score -1):

> http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/281865.html
>   http://qiita.com/lindoll/items/c94510a4da799de11ae4
>   エラー番号１１１，接続は拒否されました．

頻繁に書き込んだ時だけ起こるのであればサーバーが処理落ちしてしまったのかもしれませんね。タイマーを設定する等して接続頻度を控えても発生しますか？

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。

batch処理を行う際にループ毎にsleepを挟むと落ちませんでした。

新たな質問で恐縮ですが、
書き込む量は少なくし、10台で同時に書き込むとまた落ちてしまいました。数台だと問題ありません。
同時書き込みの制限などご存じないでしょうか？

Comment: 返信が遅れてしまいました。書き込んでいる台数が判定できればifを使えると思います。